# How to add an array into an array within a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am trying to create a personal computer program that will let me quickly add recipes into a database and be easily viewed by category. My basic setup for the information is to have a jagged array of the categories, each having an array of the recipes in that category. I have searched for a solution, but found nothing that seemed to answer my specific need. Below is basically how my data is structured.

```
//Full List
string[][][][][] arrA = {
    //List Category
    string[][][][] arrB = {
        //Single Entry
        string[][][] arrC = {
            //Entry Subsection
            string[][] arrD = {
                //Entry Value
                string[] arrE = {
                    "foo", "bar"
                },
                //Entry Value
                string[] arrF = {
                    "bar", "foo"
                }
            }
        }
        //Add Array here
    }
    //List Category
    string[][][][] arrB = {
    //Single Entry
    //Etc...
    }
}
```

And effectively what the array to add above where it says `Add Array Here`

```
//Array to add (Entry in Category)
string[][][][] arrV = {
    string[][][] arrW = {
        string[][] arrX = {
            string[] arrY = {
                "rab", "oof"
            },
            string[] arrZ = {
                "oof", "rab"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it is not possible to do this with an array, I am willing to put in a converter code so long as it can be converted back to an array as my display code is written to work with this jagged array structure.

Comment: Can I ask why you've chosen a jagged array as your main data structure? This is highly complex to operate upon and I'm certain it can be broken into more easily maintained pieces of code.

Comment: A confusing coordination of making sure the correct array is placed in the correct position is precisely why using that many levels of nested arrays is almost never a good design idea.

Comment: I have been using javascript quite a bit lately, so for some odd reason I don't quite get myself, I can mentally map how the jagged arrays work better than the other C# data options I have tried while trying to get the XML serialization to work (which I finally figured out on jagged arrays after trying and failing on multiple data types).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For your problem**

It seems that nested `List`s could solve it. Something on the lines of:

```
var entireList = new List<List<List<List<List<string>>>>>();
var allCategories = new List<List<List<List<string>>>>(); 
and so on...
```

Then you could do

```
entireList.Add(allCategories);
and so on...
```

I presume that the first element of each `List` names the list. e.g For List of `Categories` the first element would name the actual category to which the following elements belong to.

**For a solution**

How do you plan to store this List in the database? 
I recommend that you create tables and database schema design first. i.e A table for categories, etc. Then use an ORM like EnityFramework to connect to the database and then access each entity as required.
Doing this should relive you of the pain of representing the data in the way your are currently doing.

Comment: I currently have the data being serialized into an XML document. Are nested lists able to be serialized the same way?

Comment: This solution comes with many of the same headaches that are associated with having so many nested arrays. Abstract the solution out into various classes, each with appropriate data structures as necessary and this will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: @james, that is what the solution section of my answer describes

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem you've defined I see no reason why this many nested and multidimensional arrays is your chosen data structure. It's certainly more trouble than it's worth.

I'd recommend using a mapping from category to the array of recipes in that category.

```
class Recipe 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> ingredients { get; set; }
    // ... other things the class needs
}

class MyCookbook 
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Recipe>> categories = new Dictionary();

    // Creating a single recipe and giving it ingredients
    var penne = new Recipe();
    penne.name = "Penne";
    penne.ingredients = new List<string>();
    penne.ingredients.add("Tomato Sauce");
    // ... add other ingredients

    // Creating a list of recipes we will associate with some category
    var typesOfPasta = new List<Recipe>();
    typesOfPasta.add(penne);

    // Putting that list of recipes into a category, this time "Pasta"
    categories.add("Pasta", typesOfPasta);
}
```

This is a basic setup that you can expand upon that would allow you to have a string (say "pasta") pointing to an array of Recipe objects (say "lasagna", "spaghetti and meatballs", etc) where each Recipe object contains a list of necessary ingredients for that recipe.

Comment: And how would you go about pulling these entries out for display in the program? The main purpose of this program is to automatically sort and display the recipes based on the category (tabControl GUI object) and recipe name (clickable list on each side of the category)

Comment: If you need to access the entries you can use bracket notation on a List (e.g. `typesOfPasta[0]` would be the recipe object we defined called `penne`) I suggest reading up on how to use Lists and Dictionaries in C#.
Please accept and upvote my answer if it has helped you.
List - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx
Dictionary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have been trying to implement this type of restructure for a good bit now, and I think there is an issue of mismatch between the C# version you are using, and the one I am using. The two main mismatches I am finding: `var penne = new Recipe();` does not work in mine, my MVS insists on it being `List<Recipe> penne = new List<Recipe>();`. Also `public Dictionary<string, List<Recipe>> categories = new Dictionary();` is being changed to `public Dictionary<string, List<Recipe>> categories = new Dictionary<string, List<Recipe>>();` along with `categories` not being able to be referenced for `.add`

Comment: @AeonEternity The dictionary class provided by C# definitely has a `.add()` method. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx. I don't know what system you're using as you haven't provided enough detail, so I can't say for sure why it recommends `List<Recipe>` over a single `Recipe` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mat [][] = new int [5][];
int [] numbers = new int[5];      //{ v1, v2, v3, v5, v6};  Vn: variable

var arr1 = numbers.ToArray();

mat[0] = arr1;  //  o.K

mat[0] = numbers; // K.O
```

Comment: Consider adding some text explanation in your answer for what you did and why.